# Incremental sales Output

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table like Bikes

```
name    mfgdate                qtysold 

bajaj   1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM    48
bajaj   1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM    49
bajaj   1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM    50
pulsar  1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM    300
pulsar  1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM    250
pulsar  1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM    200
yamaha  1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM    90
yamaha  1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM    180
yamaha  1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM    100
```

From the above table i need a select Query to get the output of the increased sales 
like

**eg: output**

```
 name
 Bajaj
```

because Bajaj has the increased sales. Yamaha also have a increased sales but it decreased in 2018..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: yamaha has increased from 90 to 180,and decreased to 100, still an incease over 90. why it is not coming

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i need only the increased sales of all time.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala didn't tried any.

Comment: @Benny Then, why yamaha is not coming ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yamaha has decreased on 2018. so it will not come.

Comment: So you only want a `name` if it's most recent record *(2018 in the example)* is an increase on its preceding record *(2017 in the example)*?  *(So if Yamaha went 100 => 50 => 90, then it **would** be included?)*

Comment: @MatBailie no.. it's like only the increased sales like 10->20->30  not like 30 ->10->20. the second one is also increased but only in the end..

Comment: @Benny so, you only want names where there is an increase in each and every year?

Comment: Are you using MariaDB or MySQL?  MariaDB is based on MySQL but has different functionality and syntax that MySQL doesn't have.

Comment: @MatBailie using mariadb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SELF JOIN` to get desired result. Inner query will return the names of all `Bikes` which have a dip in sales. You can use `NOT IN` clause then to find the left-out result entries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name
FROM Bikes b
WHERE
b.name NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT b1.name
    FROM
    Bikes b1
    INNER JOIN
    Bikes b2
    ON b1.name = b2.name
       AND b1.mfgdate < b2.mfgdate
       AND b1.qtysold > b2.qtysold
);
```

Comment: The `WHERE` in the sub-query should be `ON`?

Comment: @Benny what lead you to conclude that this is the best answer?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441433/incremental-sales-output?noredirect=1#comment91825762_52441433), it is required to find only those Bike names, which has never seen decrease in sales.

- Following solution will work on **All MySQL Versions (especially < 8.0)**
- Using a [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), we find previous qtysold value for a bike. If not found, using [Ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, consider it as zero
- Calculate change (qtysold - previous qtysold)
- Now, using this as [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we can get all those `Distinct` bike name(s), where change has always been > 0

You can try the following (check **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe4273/1)**):

```
SELECT t3.name 
FROM 
(
SELECT t1.name, 
       (t1.qtysold - IFNULL(
                            (SELECT t2.qtysold 
                            FROM Bikes as t2 
                            WHERE t2.name = t1.name 
                              AND t2.mfgdate < t1.mfgdate 
                            ORDER BY t2.mfgdate DESC LIMIT 1)
                            , 0
                           )) AS sales_change 
FROM Bikes as t1
) AS t3 
GROUP BY t3.name 
HAVING MIN(t3.sales_change) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*, 
       sum(case when exists (select 1 
                             from table t1 
                             where t1.name = t.name and t1.mfgdate > t.mfgdate and t1.qtysold < t.qtysold
                            ) 
                then 1 else 0 end
          ) over (partition by name) as grp
from table t;
```

Now you can filter out the names which has increaed sales :

```
select t.*
from ( <subquery here> ) t
where t.grp = 0;
```

Comment: getting the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by name) as grp 
from bikes t' at line 6"

Comment: @Benny. . . Make sure you have a valid table name instead of `table`.

Comment: yep changed but the error shows near over (partition by name)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Self Join:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Bikes      AS this_year
LEFT JOIN
  Bikes      AS prev_year
    ON  prev_year.name    = this_year.name
    AND prev_year.mfgdate = DATE_SUB(this_year.mfgdate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY
  this_year.name
HAVING
  MIN(this_year.qtysold - COALESCE(prev_year.qtysold, 0)) > 0
```

MariaDB LAG():

```
WITH
  historicised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(qtysold) OVER (PARTITION BY name
                           ORDER BY mfgdate
                      )
                        AS prev_qtysold
  FROM
    Bikes
)
SELECT
  name
FROM
  historicised
GROUP BY
  name
HAVING
  MIN(qtysold - COALESCE(prev_qtysold, 0)) > 0
```